# Why am I receiving a 404 error when building a web project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web

I’m very new to web development and I have come across a strange error; I am using Visual Studio 2015 along with MVC.

When the code is left in `Startup.cs` the web page loads correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace helloworld
{
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {


        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>The World</h2>
        </body>
        </html>";

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);
        });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
}
```

However when I take out the HTML between `app.Run` to `await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);`
and put it in it's own index file and remove it from `startup.cs` I get a 404 error. I've set the port to use 8000; I apologise if this is vague and any help would be massively appreciated.

--Edited to show final code:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
    //    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    //    app.Run(async (context) =>
    //    {
    //        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
    //<html>
    //<head>
    //</head>
    //<body>
    //    <h2>The World</h2>
    //</body>
    //</html>";
    //        await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);
    //    });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

}

The code that is inside `index.html` is identical to the HTML in `startup.cs` (without the enclosing @"" etc.).

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about the question. What is your final code like? You don't need to put using statements. Post minimal and more precise to get help.

Comment: what did you do? in MVC using the action and the routing algorithm makes the bulk of the work. You should see one of the tutorials that are around to see first what it means to develop in mvc.

Comment: I've updated my code; essentially when running the app or trying to view it through localhost on a browser I receive a 404 error with the above HTML blanked out after I have moved it into it's own index file that is in wwwroot, I have very limited knowledge with web development. My apologies.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas at all? This is really starting to confuse me as I can't seem to find any obvious reason as to why it may not work.

Comment: Sorry man, but in asp.net mvc pattern you have 2 elements for render simple page. The controller with post and get action for page; and the view associated with controller action. In a nutshell, in controller folder you have a class aController with method actionresult index() and in folder View in the same name of controlle folder you have a html file for your action. 
for more info http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp